# Java question: trying to create and draw a random number of objects

Tags: java

I'm a Java novice taking a beginning programming class and I'm trying to finish my homework assignment (due tomorrow!) and I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the basic assignment:

1. create a Building class that takes parameters for x and y location - this I have done no problem
2. use a Panel class to draw a random number of Buildings - this is where I am having the trouble.

I have done this kind of thing many times in Actionscript and Javascript but for some reason I cannot get it to work in Java.

my strategy has been:
create a random number r (done)
set a 'for' loop to run from 0 to r
call the constructor for a new Building
add that Building to an Array (or an ArrayList)
draw the Building
end for loop

I have tried multiple variations of this (using an Array instead of an ArrayList for ex) but here is my current code:

here is my code:

```
public class CityPanel extends JPanel
{
 private Bldg bldg
 ArrayList<Bldg> bs = new ArrayList<Bldg>();


 //------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //Constructor; Creates five building objects
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------

 public CityPanel()
 {



  setPreferredSize (new Dimension(430, 400));
  setBackground (new Color(0x46, 0x82, 0xb4));
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //Draws this panel by requesting each object draw itself.
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------

 public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
 {
  int b = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  for( int i = 0; i < b; i++ ) {
   intArr[i] = new Integer( i );
   bldg = new Bldg(100*i, 300);
   bs.add(bldg);
   super.paintComponent(page);
   bldg.draw(page);
   System.out.print(bs.get(i).toString());
  }
}
```

when I run the main program (a City class that draws the panels etc) I get an empty frame.

if I just put in a constructor function without the 'for' loop I get the Building(s) to draw, so the problem lies somewhere in my 'for' loop and the way I'm trying to make and/or store the objects.

when I google "java creating multiple objects" or "random" or what-have-you I get a lot or results but nothing relevant!

sorry for the long post - I'm not sure how to ask the question!

thanks in advance.
b

Comment: You really need to format the source code correctly, or no-one will bother reading it.

Comment: I would create the buildings once and only paint them in `paintComponent`. That method is called potentially *many* times and you'd get different buildings any time you resize the window or (on older systems) move another window on top of it. Also you are creating many more buildings than you want, as you never clear the `ArrayList<Building>`.

Comment: why do you paint the page b times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your buildings in the constructor

```
int b = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

for( int i = 0; i < b; i++ ) {
   bldg = new Bldg(100*i, 300);
   bs.add(bldg);
}
```

and then change your paintComponent to

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
   super.paintComponent(page);

   for (Building bldg : bs) {
     bldg.draw(page);
   }
}
```

Give that a try.  You should only call super.paintComponent once

Comment: +1, because paint() is called multiple times by the system, and because super.paintComponent() will fill everything with the background color and erase your buildings.

Comment: Yup - sure enough, that was it! 
Thanks to you guys for the help! relieved that it was something simple. I was beating my head against the table for hours with this one.

Comment: @Jesper - you really should make your criticism constructive, or no one will read it.